# adding CMS functionailty to a rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, string, content-management-system

I guess I'm looking to add some CMS type functionality to my web app.  In it's simplest form I will create some content, store it, and then call it in a view.

I have an "article" model with art_name and art_content string fields.
in some "Pages" controller I store a variable of the particular article I would like displayed on a page as:

```
@article_wanted = article.find(5).art_content
```

In a view I call this variable `<%= @article_wanted %>`and the string in the art_content of the appropriate model (ID 5 in this example) is output.  This is great... however I would like to store html as my art_content string so I can add h1 tags, css classes,...etc.  By using my current methodology the art_content string is displayed on the browser as it was saved (tags visible) `<h1>article content header</h1>`.  I think that because I've defined the model field as a string the tags are converted:
`&lt;h1&gt;art content header&lt;/h1&gt;`

How do I get around this?

is there a better way to publish articles to a page that is better than my current method?  where I'm calling a controller variable, from an html content field of some model, in a view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really address the question of wanting full CMS functionality (google "rails cms"), but did you try `<%= raw @article_wanted %>`?

Comment: Or, you can also use '<%= h @article_wanted %>' . BTW `article.find(5).art_content` should be `Article.find(5)`

Comment: article.find(5) will retrieve a member of the table; find(5).art)content takes the "art_content" field values for the 5th member.   =h didn't seem to do it.

Comment: raw worked.... Thanks!  rails cms comes up with a bunch of existing fully equipped CMS; I'm looking to re-invent the wheel to learn on a few aspects of it.